# How to cut string from string in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
page=@"<html><body><p>look at me</p><p>right</p></body></html>";
```

I need "look at me" from this string if I don't know when "look at me" starts and its length
but I know that "look at me" there is after `<p>` and before `</p>`
I need new string like that

```
text=@"look at me";
```

Comment: If possible be more clear about what part of the string will always be the same.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the content within a certain pair of tags? You may want to add an id or class attribute to the tag you want to grab, first of all.

Comment: and if I add what should I do after that?

Comment: Hey! If my answer was helpful, please accept it. Otherwise, please provide further information.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this:

```
NSString* yourResult;

NSScanner *htmlScanner =  [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourHtml];

//Video-Start finden
[htmlScanner scanUpToString:@"<p>" intoString:NULL];
[htmlScanner scanString:@"<p>" intoString:NULL];

[htmlScanner scanUpToString:@"</p>" intoString:&yourResult];
```

This should give you the first string between

tags. If you want to extract more than one result, you could loop this, until `yourResult` stays nil.

Comment: I always forget about NSScanner, it really is pretty convenient for things like this!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input string is always well-formed XML (XHTML -- plain HTML isn't) you could process it through an XML processor (XML DOM or an XML Reader). Alternatively you can do it through Regular Expressions, which would work even if your input can be other than well-formed XML.

Comment: Or use [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple), which is nice cozy Objective-C and tolerance of bad HTML.